# How can I solve this error in SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error with a server about a request to the DB.

This is the message:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', regione='e', provincia='q', comune='w'' at line 1

This is the quesry SQL in question:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM azienda WHERE id_categoria=?, 
regione=?, provincia=?, comune=?");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ps.setString(2, regione);
        ps.setString(3, provincia);
        ps.setString(4, comune);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the sql query, and not the code used to generate that query (which is mostly a distraction here), would make it more obvious why that that isn't valid sql.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei I do the control about the parameters in a servlet. However the solution of draz seems to work. thank you!

Comment: @AD7six you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use AND if you are using multiple conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM azienda 
WHERE id_categoria=? 
AND regione=? 
AND provincia=? 
AND comune=?
```

Comment: Thank you man! I tried it and it seems to work